# Setting a [CSS] :hover and :checked condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a :hover effect applied --

```
td img.off{
    display:none;
}

td:hover img.off{
    display:inline;
}

td:hover img.on{
    display:none;
}
```

-- on some images.

```
<td>
    <div class="col1"><img class="on" src="1.bmp"></div>
    <div class="col1"><img class="off" src="2.bmp"></div>
</td>
```

I'm trying to add a checkbox that disables the hover effect if it's active, so I tried to do --

```
input:checked + td:hover img.off{
    display:inline;
}

input:checked + td:hover img.on{
    display:none;
}
```

-- with this checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box" class="cbox">
```

But it didn't work. I'm looking for a HTML/CSS solution to this. Anyone know why it's not working?

EDIT: What's wrong here? EDIT^2: Sibling selector. Can't even.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
label[for="chkbox1"] {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
input:checked + .header label:after {
  content: 'X';
}
table td img.off{
  display:none;
}
input:checked + table td:hover img.off{
  display:inline;
}
input:checked + table td:hover img.on{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input id="chkbox1" type="checkbox" name="box" class="cbox">

<div class="header">
  <label for="chkbox1"></label>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="col1">
        <img class="on" src="http://placehold.it/50">
      </div>
      <div class="col1">
        <img class="off" src="http://placehold.it/100">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: `input:checked + td:hover` means that the checkbox would be the immediate preceding sibling of the td.  That doesn't make sense structurally, so I'm guessing you don't actually have your HTML in that order.

Comment: the checkbox is in the header. Is there a way to make it make sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your posted code I assume the below markup.

The sibling selector `+` target a sibling and in below case it will be the `table`, not the `td`

```css
input:checked + table td:hover img.on {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="box" class="cbox">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="col1">
        <img class="on" src="http://placehold.it/50">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want the checkbox to be in the header, you'll need to do a trick using a label, like this

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
label[for="chkbox1"] {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
input:checked ~ table td:hover img.on {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
input:checked + .header label:after {
  content: 'X';
}
```

```html
<input id="chkbox1" type="checkbox" name="box" class="cbox">

<div class="header">
  <label for="chkbox1"></label>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="col1">
        <img class="on" src="http://placehold.it/50">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To clarify what will NOT work, below sample, as the actual `checkbox` is a child of the `header` and can't reach the `img` using the sibling selector.

For this to work a parent selector would be needed and those does not exist (yet)

```css
input:checked ~ table td:hover img.on {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <input id="chkbox1" type="checkbox" name="box" class="cbox">
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="col1">
        <img class="on" src="http://placehold.it/50">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Update after question edit

You need to use the `~` sibling selector, not the immediate sibling selector `+`, as the `table` does not come as an immediate sibling of the `input`

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
label[for="chkbox1"] {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
input:checked + .header label:after {
  content: 'X';
}
table td img.off {
  display:none;
}
input:checked ~ table td:hover img.off {
  display:inline;
}
input:checked ~ table td:hover img.on {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input id="chkbox1" type="checkbox" name="box" class="cbox">

<div class="header">
  <label for="chkbox1"></label>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="col1">
        <img class="on" src="http://placehold.it/50/0f0">
      </div>
      <div class="col1">
        <img class="off" src="http://placehold.it/100/0ff">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, when I said header, I meant that I had a "header."

As in, a defined section(?)
            header { }. It would work the way I want it to if it were outside that header. Is there a way to adjust it?

Comment: @AlexG As long as the actual `checkbox` is a sibling to the element you want it to interact with, it will work fine without a label.

Comment: @AlexG Updated my answer with a "header"

Comment: Something really strange is going on. I can no longer select the checkbox? Is it now essentially a picture?

Comment: @AlexG Updated my answer again, with a 3:rd sample showing what will NOT work

Comment: I understand why it doesn't work, I think. Is there a significant difference between creating something like <header>...</header> and <div class="header">...</div>? @LGSon

Comment: @AlexG No, when you put the real checkbox inside another element, no matter which, you loose the ability to use its checked state to control an element in another element group, as showed in 3:rd sample, that's why you need the label, as in 2:nd sample, where it "pretends" to be the checkbox

Comment: I added an edit of something very similar to what I'm getting. Do you know what that's happening? @LGSon

Comment: @AlexG Updated my answer with a 5:th sample/explanation

Comment: This has literally taken me hours. Not all heroes wear capes.

Comment: Also, I had no idea that "+" was a "sibling selector." This stuff's confusing af. You kept telling me... but it just kept going over my head. ("Why is there a not sign there??")

Comment: @AlexG Well, now your know what and how to use them ... :)

Comment: much obliged! @LGSon